# Run-time error '2522' - The action or method requires a File Name argument

Tags: vba, ms-access, windows-10, runtime-error

I recently received a new laptop at work with Windows 10 (64-bit machine). I'm fairly new to VBA/Access and figured out how to get Access to operate on the 64-bit machine.

I am now encountering an issue with a browse button where a user (myself) clicks on a button that then directs me to choose the file. I did not create this database so I am just a secondary user.

Now when I click on it I am receiving a VBA error: Run-time error '2522' - The action or method requires a File Name argument

This is the argument that it is pointing to: `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "tempDemographics", strInputFileName, True`

Any idea on what can fix this? I've included the full code below:

```
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim strInputFileName As String

    strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, "Excel Files (*.xls*)", "*.xls*")
    strInputFileName = ahtCommonFileOpenSave( _
    Filter:=strFilter, OpenFile:=True, _
    DialogTitle:="Select Facilities Extract...", _
    Flags:=ahtOFN_HIDEREADONLY)

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "tempDemographics", strInputFileName, True
```

UPDATE:

I tried running a breakpoint at the DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet..... line. Once I do that and it takes me right back to the VBA dialogue.

Also, here is the full code for reference:

```
Private Sub cmdDemographics_Click()

'turn off warnings
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
'delete current Demographics data
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM tblDemographics"

'Upload Facilities Extract into tempTable

Dim strFilter As String
Dim strInputFileName As String
strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, "Excel Files (*.xls*)", "*.xls*")
strInputFileName = ahtCommonFileOpenSave( _
Filter:=strFilter, OpenFile:=True, _
DialogTitle:="Select Facilities Extract...", _
Flags:=ahtOFN_HIDEREADONLY)
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "tempDemographics", strInputFileName, True

'create Demographics table (include SupervisorID)
DoCmd.OpenQuery "AppendDemographics"

'generate and display exception report
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptExceptions", acViewPreview

'remove tempDemographics Data
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM tempDemographics"

'add in X sitecode for unmapped TNPs
addXSiteCode

MsgBox "Demographics File Imported Sucessfully"

'turn warnings back on
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

To clarify:

The issue I am having is during the import. The Import is pointing to a macro button which I click on, then it will bring up a dialogue box to point to the excel file that I wish to import. As of right now when I click on the macro button I am receiving the run-time error 2522 message.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` instruction (F9 to toggle), run the code; does `strInputFileName` have the expected value when the breakpoint is hit? What happens if the file dialog is cancelled?

Comment: Breakpoints don't fix problems, they're a debugging tool. You run the code and execution stops at the breakpoint *and then you can inspect variables and their values and see if everything is the way you're expecting it to be*.

Comment: Please don't put code in comments, [edit] your post instead.

Comment: You need to put the breakpoint *on*, or *before* that statement, so you can inspect its inputs *before* VBA tries to run it with bad inputs and blows up.

Comment: @RickSmith Check the value of that `strInputFileName` variable.  The error message suggests its value is not a valid file path to an Excel workbook file.  In debug (break) mode, you can look in the Watch window or paste `? strInputFileName ` into the Immediate window and press Enter.

Comment: The problem is most likely in `ahtAddFilterItem` or `ahtCommonFileOpenSave`. Especially if you made changes to make it 64-bit compatible, because that's easy to screw up. However, you haven't shared that.

Comment: Hi @HansUp - when I put the strInputFileName in the immediate window and hit enter I received the compile error: expected sub, function, or property

Comment: @ErikA - I added ptrsafe to private declares where visible. I am fairly new to VBA and that is the workaround I found when utilizing older versions of access on the new 64 bit machine.

Comment: @RickSmith Include the question mark before the variable name like this `? strInputFileName`

Comment: @Rick `ptrsafe` is not just some silly word you need to add to have it work on 64-bit systems. You're supposed to check if the function uses pointers, and if it does, rework the definition to make it safe for 64-bits